# Where Should I put my Login PHP script (for controller ) in CodeIngiter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a simple question.
 
In my Home controller, there is a function for Log in, inside the function there is the account control for

- Sql Databse (Accounts saved in a Database, like the root account)
- LDAP

For the LDAP i have a seperate file with contains a function to validate the LDAP accounts.

---

My question is, should i put the file inside the 'helper' folder, put in a model or add the function in the controller.

This is simply for better organization.

Comment: whatever suits you better, actually... CI isn't super strict about enforcing MVC so you can do everything in the way you're most comformatable with. Having said that, my recommended approach would be to have an auth-specific controller (in my projects it's generally called "Auth") and within that you'd have methods for processing a database login, an LDAP login, a social login, processing logouts, etc.).

Comment: Thanks alot. I think im going to add the function inside the controller and call it from whitin other function

Comment: That should work. Also, if you have multiple controllers, you may add a session check on each controller's construct and automatically redirect the user to your auth controller if you find no valid session already set. That way you can secure your app with not too much hassle